# Sequence Creation With Abstract/Concrete Syntax (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket, abstract-syntax-tree

To start off, this is homework. It isn't my intention to get a complete solution, but I am stuck with how to interpret this problem.

We're basically making an interpreter from a lexer and parser for a language that we have created in class.

Specifically, what I am stuck on is using Scheme/Drracket to implement creating a sequence using the parser that calls the method "make-seq" that can be defined by the following rules:

```
(make-seq (e)) = e
(make-seq (e1 e2 ... en)) = (make-let '*temp* e1 (make-seq (e2 ... en)))
```

Where make-let is defined as:

```
(define (make-let var exp1 exp2)
  (list 'let var exp1 exp2))
```

I've implemented the make-seq method below:

```
(define (make-seq e)
  (if (null? (cdr e))
      e
      (make-let '*temp* (car e) (make-seq (cdr e)))))
```

but I am not sure how to represent the '*temp* in the rules above. I am fairly certain that I should not have the symbol '*temp* actually in the implementation, but I'm not sure what I should be doing there instead.

Could anyone give me pointers as to how I should move forward with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `gensym` to generate a unique tag that will never clash with an identifier in the object language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `*temp` won't be a problem unless the program it's interpreting also has `*test`:

```
(let ((*temp 10))
  (seq
    expression1
    (* *temp *temp))) ; end up using the result from the previous element in the sequence
```

To fix this you can introduce variables that are ok for the interpreter but not possible to create in code. I've often used symbols and lists where the first element is a special value. Your `make-seq` creates that instead and your interpreter needs to treat those as symbols too. Usually the interpreter uses `eq?` so basically every structure created as a list with a tag will be unique for that expansion making each nesting `*temp` not even bother the other ones created earlier.